# Convert JSON string to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of arrays which I have planted in the DOM, so that I can reuse it at a later stage to transfer to the server:

```
[["1","aaaaaa","1"],["2","bbbbbbb","2"],["3","ccccccc","3"]]
```

If I would like to convert it back into a Javascript array, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: That's not JSON. That already is an array.

Comment: @Diodeus: *"...which I have planted in the DOM..."* I'm guessing OP is showing text content that is hidden somewhere in the page.

Comment: @tereško: I don't think that's a duplicate. Seems that OP is going the other direction.

Comment: @amnotiam you're correct, found a correct duplicate

Comment: @tereško: Here's the deal. I don't care about rep. I wish this site didn't have this meaningless rep system. Fact is that sometimes it's just faster to answer the question than go searching around. Seems like the vast majority of the questions here *(in the JS/jQuery tag anyway)* are posted by people who just don't want to put forth the effort to find the answer themselves. Since StackOverflow doesn't *really* have any way of preventing duplicates *(since most dupes are never closed)*, I figure we might as well just answer the thing, and get it out of the way.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('[["1","aaaaaa","1"],["2","bbbbbbb","2"],["3","ccccccc","3"]]')
```

Assuming jquery is ok to use because of tag.

Comment: You are using jQuery. But what is the function to use in plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 58):

If the browzer has the `JSON` object then

```
JSON.parse(string);
```

or if you have `jQuery`

```
$.parseJSON(string);
```

Comment: If anyone wants to know the difference between the two functions (apart from that one requires jQuery) [this is quite a good read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10362313/3722330)

Answer (score 17):

```
var array = JSON.parse(my_JSON)
```

Answer (score 14):

**[jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)**

```
var myArr = $.parseJSON(myJsonString);
```