# jQuery.parseJSON vs JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery

[`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) are two functions that perform the same task. If the jQuery library is already loaded, would using `jQuery.parseJSON` be better than using `JSON.parse`, in terms of performance?

If yes, why? If no, why not?

Comment: I think JSON.parse isn't avaible at old browsers. In terms of speed they should be identical, JSON.parse should be little more faster (I think jQuery uses JSON.parse in newer browsers).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Here is an extract [from jQuery 1.9.1](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/28d946384799abcd7608c3beda898a0a11ac88d7/src/core.js#L518-L546):

```js
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }

    if ( data === null ) {
        return data;
    }

    if ( typeof data === "string" ) {

        // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
        data = jQuery.trim( data );

        if ( data ) {
            // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
            // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
            if ( rvalidchars.test( data.replace( rvalidescape, "@" )
                .replace( rvalidtokens, "]" )
                .replace( rvalidbraces, "")) ) {

                return ( new Function( "return " + data ) )();
            }
        }
    }

    jQuery.error( "Invalid JSON: " + data );
},
```

As you can see, jQuery will use the native `JSON.parse` method if it is available, and otherwise it will try to evaluate the data with `new Function`, which is kind of like `eval`.

So yes, you should definitely use `jQuery.parseJSON`.

Comment: Wow, great answers! Thanks everyone, I think yours is the most comprehensive answer.

Comment: Depending on where your json comes from, there may be security issues with the fallback 'eval' method.

Comment: The rvalidchars.test stuff should catch invalid JSON; so this looks pretty safe.

Comment: Note that this is old, and an empty string will no longer return null. It will instead throw an error.

Comment: Yes, I think this answer should be updated to state that it's almost unnecessary to use a big library like jQuery for this. Gonna report Joseph the Dreamer's link to show the browser adoption of `JSON.parse`:
http://caniuse.com/#search=json

Answer (score 12):

[According to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

> Where the browser provides a native implementation of JSON.parse, jQuery uses it to parse the string.

thus it means that jQuery provides a JSON parser if no native implementation exists on the browser. [here's a comparison chart](http://caniuse.com/#search=json) of browsers that have (and don't have) JSON functionality

Answer (score 7):

If you're using jQuery version 3 (released in 2016) then you should use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) because `jQuery.parseJSON()` [has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

> As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON objects, use the native JSON.parse method instead.

Answer (score 6):

JSON.parse() is natively available on some browsers, not on others, so it's safer to use a library. The JQuery implementation works well, as other respondents have noted. There's also [Douglas Crockford's JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), which uses the native implementation if available.

The JSON library has the advantage that it has a method to turn a JavaScript object into a JSON string, which is missing from jQuery at the moment..

Comment: Best answer because it indicates why the JSON library by Douglas Crockford is still necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about performance, but it's definitely safer to use the jQuery method because some browsers like ie7 and lower might not have any JSON functionalities natively.
It's all about compatibility, just like you use jQuery's each method instead of the array's native `forEach` method for iteration.

Comment: I always use JSON.parse(date) because of I never support IE8-
and less characters than $.parseJSON() ^_^

For IE8- let's use like this 

<!--[if lt IE 8]><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=/error-browser.html"><![endif]-->

Answer (score 2):

Talking about **performance**, the **most updated** answer is **`JSON.parse`**.

The native JSON object is **supported** in **every browser** nowadays, so opt for `JSON.parse`. You can see the support table here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=json

You can also search for this alias appearances at JQuery's repository on GitHub: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=parseJSON

Also, `jQuery.parseJson` was **deprecated** on version 3.0+ as mentioned by other answers here.

You should only use jQuery's version if you're an old JQuery version + if you want to provide support for very old browsers (normally, **not recommended**).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery internally uses `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON file.So it doesn't make any difference in most cases.

But some of the older browsers don't support `JSON.parse` functionality.In that case using `jQuery.parseJSON` is beneficial as jQuery can handle JSON using its own function.

NOTE:

> `jQuery.parseJSON` is deprecated from jQuery 3.0.So please use the native `JSON.parse` method.