# Split string in Java with special symbol in first occurence only?

Tags: java, regex, json, string, split

I want to display the java list data in the html page. 
So i decided it is better to work with JSON. I converted the list into json string object. 
Using Jquery i can parse and display the info in the list. 
I converted the list into json object. It is converted as follows:

`{"list":[{"one":"11","two":"21","three":31},{"one":"12","two":"22","three":32},{"one":"13","two":"23","three":33}]}`

But I came to know that the syntax is little mismatched to parse by jQuery.
jQuery is handling the following one only as I came to know by googling:

`'[{"one":"11","two":"21","three":31},{"one":"12","two":"22","three":32},{"one":"13","two":"23","three":33}]'`

I just want to discard the substring occurrence of `:`(colon)  and last char `{` also discards, Then I can pass this `json` object and jQuery is handling well. I tried with the both strings, only second one works.  How can I discard the substring with the first occurrence of `:` with regex?

Comment: Why you only use jquery? Javascript also parse your json too.http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: @swemon Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362277/jquery-parsejson-vs-json-parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery could handle both. (They are both right JSON format.)

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

// for the first type
var arr = obj.list;

// for the second type obj is already an array.
```

***[Check the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/QarnP/)***

Comment: Hi xdazz, I tried but it is not working with the first example code.. only working with second example code..

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary Check the demo I added.

Comment: I checked it.. Working well. I just not aware of adding the name as $.parseJSON(string1).list);.. Finally i got to know.. Thanks a lot xdazz... For your time with Me...

Answer (score 3):

Following code will give you required string:

```
String str = "{"list":[{"one":"11","two":"21","three":31},{"one":"12","two":"22","three":32},{"one":"13","two":"23","three":33}]}" // Escape the Quotes to include in str

str = str.substring(str.indexOf(':')+1,str.length()-1);
```