# Converting String Object to Json Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

`" {"error":"ApplicationException","reason":"Data types of key columns do not match. 'USERS.lastmodifiedtime' is of 'TIMESTAMP', 'state_list.name' is of 'VARCHAR'."} "`

Is stored in string format, I need it in json format

Comment: JSON is a string format, so it's already JSON.

Comment: In regards to the various answers here -- if you're trying to decide whether to use JSON.parse or jQuery.parseJSON, you should be aware that the jQuery version is better for cross-browser compatibility. See the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362277/jquery-parsejson-vs-json-parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> jQuery.parseJSON( json )

example

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"error":"ApplicationException"}');
```

for more info [see details](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 4):

Modern browsers have built in parser [`JSON.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

If you have to support older browsers you can add [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)/[json3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/) libraries. These will add the JSON.parse support if native support is not present in the browser.

If the string is not valid then a parse error will be thrown, in your case it looks like you may have to escape the `'`s.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the JSON-*string*<sup>**1**</sup> to `Object`, `parse` it. You should mind escaping apostrophes here:

```
JSON.parse('{"error":"ApplicationException","reason":"Data types of key columns do not match. \'USERS.lastmodifiedtime\' is of \'TIMESTAMP\', \'state_list.name\' is of \'VARCHAR\'."}')
```

<sup>**1**</sup> JSON: **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject ***N**otation*

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"error":"ApplicationException"}');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (jQuery)

```
$.parseJSON(STRING);
```