# Ajax result is not an object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

My AJAX result is

```
["1","O"]
```

I'm trying to access 1, but

```
console.log(result[0]);
```

gives me

> '['

How can I make it as an object and get just the first element of my array result?

Comment: You may want to consider Douglas Crockford's [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to ensure compatability of `JSON.parse` across browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are indexing into the string of your result. Try

```
var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(resultsObj[0]);
```

Comment: So I was trying result = $.parse(result); dont we have such a thing? If yes, what is the difference!

Comment: There is a jQuery.parseJSON() but not a simple parse. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
Using jQuery provides more robustness as it will use JSON if available and otherwise try eval.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362277/jquery-parsejson-vs-json-parse

Answer (score 1):

What you're accessing is the string of the result. You need to parse it out of JSON format.

```
result = JSON.parse(result);
```

Comment: So I was trying result = $.parse(result);and not working! dont we have such a thing? If yes, what is the difference!

Comment: As Joel said, there isn't a $.parse function. Just use `JSON.parse`.