# Read Value of JSON Result in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my output of **WebMethod** through **Ajax** call:

```
 var item=""[{\"Column1\":\"false\"}]""
```

There is always one row output,i-e `true` or `false`,i want to get the value of `Column1`,i already try `Jquery.ParseJson(item)`,but it gives **Illegal Token o error**,Kindly help me how to read this value.Kindly check the **inverted commas**,this is the exact outcome of my `web method`, and this outcome and format is a necessary condition of scenario.Thanks.On using loop it gives the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that above solutions not work perfectly with your browsers, here is another alternate solution, though I know that it may not fit your scenario, but as your output is either `true` or `false` .Instead of using `JsonConvert` on server end, simply return the object array to client end and read value like this.

```
var tempo=item[0].Column1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think your extra quotes around the strings are a problem, this is invalid syntax.

This works:

```
var item = "[{\"Column1\":\"false\"}]";
var parsed = JSON.parse(item);
parsed.forEach(function(row) {
    console.log(row.Column1);
});
console.log(parsed[0].Column1);
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/Ljtax8cw/).

See here about [jQuery.ParseJson vs JSON.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362277/jquery-parsejson-vs-json-parse), I prefer JSON.parse, but either should work fine.

In the case of older browsers without `forEach` use a `for` loop or a library like underscore.

```
var item="[{\"Column1\":\"false\"}]";
var parsed = JSON.parse(item);
//if forEach is not supported:
for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
    console.log(parsed[i].Column1);
}
console.log(parsed[0].Column1);
```

Here is a for loop [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/Ljtax8cw/).

Comment: It looks like your browser does not have `forEach`. You'll have to use `for(;;)` or something like underscore if you want to support an older browser. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Bjron ...i am using Chrome having version  33.0.1750.154 dev-m

Comment: My version of Chrome is Version 37.0.2062.124, I believe that's the most recent stable version. I'd think 33 would have `forEach` it's been around for a while, but I'm not sure. You might just want to use  a for loop or a library like underscore/lodash.

Comment: on opera and firefox,it gives the error undefined is not a function

Comment: Did you try it with the `for` loop instead of the `forEach`?

Comment: Maybe you can create a jsfiddle for me to try.

Comment: Yes I try it with for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62487/discussion-between-bjorn-tipling-and-muhammad-ali).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the output of your service but I think you could try this:

```
str = 'var item=""[{\"Column1\":\"false\"}]""';
str = str.replace(/"/g, '');//remove quotes and slashes to make valid json
eval(str);//evaluate the string
console.log(item[0].Column1);
```

Comment: in str i have `"var item=[{\Column1\:\false\}]"`...but it gives `item[0].Column1` undefined