# php associative array to javascript - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying and trying. I think it has worked so far, but now it doesn't..

```
<?php
    $arr['123'] = 'QWE123';
    $arr['124'] = 'QWE124';
?>

<input id="arr" value=<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?> hidden>

<script>
    $(function (){
      var arrJS = $("#arr").val();
      console.log( arrJS );         // looks fine {"123":"QWEQWE123","124":"QWEQWE124"}
      console.log( arrJS['123'] );  // undefined !!!
    });
</script>
```

p.s. to object didn't help. `arrJS = Object( $("#arr").val() );`

Comment: print here your   `console.log( arrJS );`

Comment: try console.log( json_decode(arrJS['123']) );

Comment: You can use `var obj=  jQuery.parseJSON(arrJs);` and access as object with `->` exmp - `obj->123;`

Comment: anant kumar singh, json_decode is php func actualy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the json. You may do it like this:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(arrJS);
```

Wish it helps!

Answer (score 0):

it is just because **json_encode** convert array with double quotes `"`

when using double quotes **"** with value result will be

[image]

so change `value="<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>"` to `value='<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>'`

```
 <?php
    $arr = [];
        $arr['123'] = 'QWE123';
        $arr['124'] = 'QWE124';
    ?>

    <input id="arr" value='<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>' >

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function (){
          var arrJS = $("#arr").val();
          arrJS = JSON.parse(arrJS);
          console.log( arrJS );         
          console.log( arrJS['123'] );  
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: right, i dont use any quotes actually. here was the typing mistake

Comment: cant)) low reputation)) do you know what big different between JSON.parse and jQuery.parseJSON?

Comment: you can see the difference here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362277/jquery-parsejson-vs-json-parse