# Google Chart - uncaught error: not an array

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have a php script that generates the google chart data and returns it in json encoded format. It's loaded into google chart using jQuery $.get() method. When I pass the return data to the google "**arrayToDataTable**" function like this:

```
var googleChartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```

I get this error:

[image]

So, what I did was I dumped the value of my variable "**chartData**" and I got the following:

[image]

So, what I did was, copy this data from console window into the "**arrayToDataTable**" function manually like this:

```
var googleChartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Date Range","0001\/102\/0 Available","0001\/102\/0 Unavailable","0001\/102\/1 Available","0001\/102\/1 Unavailable"],["02\/10\/2013",0,1,110,11],["03\/10\/2013",0,1,189,11],["04\/10\/2013",0,1,189,11],["06\/10\/2013",0,1,189,10],["07\/10\/2013",0,1,187,10],["08\/10\/2013",186,11,0,1],["09\/10\/2013",186,11,0,1],["10\/10\/2013",0,1,186,11],["11\/10\/2013",0,1,204,11],["13\/10\/2013",0,1,204,11]]);
```

Now the chart renders (as expected, because the returned data from my php script is correct):

[image]

This is a bit bizarre; does any one know why the chart doesn't work when it's loaded from the variable?

Comment: For completeness, here's my javascript function http://pastebin.com/A6YFy44J and here's my cut down / dummy php script (that provides the data for chart) http://pastebin.com/LqH8C95v

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved it by changing **arrayToDataTable** line like this:

```
var googleChartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($.parseJSON(chartData));
```

Thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9420583/2332336

Comment: If should add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax calls and the JSON is formatted automagically