# Google scatter chart - {role: 'style'} {role: 'tooltip'} not working in JSON form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-visualization

I get google chart data from PHP function in json encoded format which I am passing to "arrayToDataTable" function. I am using $.ajax function. When I pass the following data to the "arrayToDataTable" function

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('[
    ["goals", "goal", {
        role: 'style'
    }, {
        role: 'tooltip'
    }],
    [54, 0.5, "#0000cf", "54%"],
    [100, 1.5, "#0000cf", "100%"],
    [97, 2.5, "#0000cf", "97%"],
    [87, 2.5, "#0000cf", "87%"]
]')

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
```

It is generating a following error. 
**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 19 of the JSON data**

If data is sent without "style" and "tooltip" columns it is generating a graph as expected.

I am following this post: [Google Chart - uncaught error: not an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400497/google-chart-uncaught-error-not-an-array)

Comment: Could you please better indent you code?

Comment: indent your json and you will see your error. Check your json : http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON, attribute names must be string.

Edit: string delimiter should always be `"` and not `'`

So

```
{
    role: 'style'
}
```

Should be

```
{
    "role": "style"
}
```

Comment: after changing code ,  getting below error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 27 of the JSON data

Comment: changed to `{
    "role": "style" 
}` its working now

Comment: Thank you for you time Apolo

Comment: I the answer solved your problem, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer. Have a good time on SO