# Google Chart - arrayToDataTable not an array error

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a backend in nodejs that generates an array and call a javascript function to plot a graph.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(value)
```

The problem that I got a uncaught error:

[image]

Printing the variable *value* I have:

```
 [ [ 'ml', 'date' ],
  [ 'Sun Nov 24 2019 13:30:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)',
    481 ],
  [ 'Sun Nov 24 2019 14:00:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)',
    571 ] ]
```

Reading similar posts like [Google Chart - uncaught error: not an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400497/google-chart-uncaught-error-not-an-array) i tried:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(values));
```

But i get the following error:

[image]

If I hardcode *values* **it works** fine:

```
var values = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['ml','date'],
    ['Sun Nov 24 2019 13:30:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)',481 ],
    ['Sun Nov 24 2019 14:00:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)',571 ]
]);

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(values);
```

I couldn't see any difference printing the variable from hardcoding.

Any ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the array is most likely being passed as a string.
if so, you need to use --> `JSON.parse`

but you need to swap the single quotes (`'`) for double quotes (`"`)

see following snippet, which works...

```js
var test = JSON.parse('[["ml","date"],["Sun Nov 24 2019 13:30:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)",481 ],["Sun Nov 24 2019 14:00:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)",571 ]]');
console.log(test);
```

while this snippet does not...

```js
var test = JSON.parse("[['ml','date'],['Sun Nov 24 2019 13:30:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)',481 ],['Sun Nov 24 2019 14:00:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)',571 ]]");
console.log(test);
```