# How to iterate json data in jquery + ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

But i get respnce in json, i.e alert(html)

```
<script>
function addcartAction(id){
var dataString='id='+id;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/testurl",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(html)
    { 

    alert(html);

        $("#cart-item").html(html);
    }
    });

}

</script>



{
        "1": {
            "ItemName": "Product1",
            "id": "1",
            "item_Image": "http://testurl.com/gallerythumb/test.JPG",
            "price": "4.99",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        "2": {
            "ItemName": "Product2",
            "id": "2",
            "item_Image": "http://testurl.com/gallerythumb/test1.jpg",
            "price": "7.99",
            "quantity": 12
        }
    }
```

I have tried alot of different syntax but can't seem to figure this out.
Can any one point me in the right direction?, so can i solve this one.

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Documentation link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your json string, use the [parseJSON() function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/), which returns an object. Then you can access it's properties as shown in the docs.

Also you might refer to:

1. [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)
2. [Convert JSON string to Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420567/convert-json-string-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** to iterate JavaScript object

```js
var data = {
  "1": {
    "ItemName": "Product1",
    "id": "1",
    "item_Image": "http://testurl.com/gallerythumb/test.JPG",
    "price": "4.99",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "ItemName": "Product2",
    "id": "2",
    "item_Image": "http://testurl.com/gallerythumb/test1.jpg",
    "price": "7.99",
    "quantity": 12
  }
};

$.each(data,function(i, v) {
  console.log(i);
  $.each(v,function( ind , val) {
    console.log( ind , val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how do i get these data responce in ajax success

Comment: success: function(data){ $.each(data,function(key,value){ alert(key); }); }

Comment: either you need to set `dataType:'json'` on you need to the data using `JSON.parse(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this!

```js
var data={
    "1": {
        "ItemName": "Product1",
        "id": "1",
        "item_Image": "http://testurl.com/gallerythumb/test.JPG",
        "price": "4.99",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    "2": {
        "ItemName": "Product2",
        "id": "2",
        "item_Image": "http://testurl.com/gallerythumb/test1.jpg",
        "price": "7.99",
        "quantity": 12
    }
};
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    var element='<div class="elem">Item No : '+key+
                ' <span>Item Name : '+value.ItemName+'</span> '+
                ' <span>Id : '+value.id+'</span> '+
                ' <img src="'+value.item_Image+'"/> '+
                ' <span>Price: '+value.price+'</span> '+
                ' <span>Quantity : '+value.quantity+'</span></div> ';
    $('body').append(element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Update**

Say you have following `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
   url:'someurl',
   type:'POST',
   dataType:'json',
   success: function(data)
   { 
       $.each(data,function(key,value){
           var element='<div class="elem">Item No : '+key+
                       ' <span>Item Name : '+value.ItemName+'</span> '+
                       ' <span>Id : '+value.id+'</span> '+
                       ' <img src="'+value.item_Image+'"/> '+
                       ' <span>Price: '+value.price+'</span> '+
                       ' <span>Quantity : '+value.quantity+'</span></div> ';
             $('body').append(element); //append it to anywhere in DOM using selector
      });
    },
    error:function(jqXHR,responseData,status){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: how do i get these data  responce in ajax success

Comment: success: function(data){ 
 
 
 
$.each(data,function(key,value){

alert(key);

});  }

Comment: @SairamGogikar Updated answer.. check and let me know!!

Comment: i passed the values as var dataString='id='+id;

Comment: where you've passed the values!! What changes you want to implement here??

Comment: Updated my question, can u check once.

Comment: Are you getting relevant data back?? as you have shown in question?

Comment: iam getting the json data

Comment: then change your `ajax success` to what I've shown here!!

Comment: instead of `$('body').append(element);` write `$('#cart-item').append(element);`

Comment: its not working, iam getting json responce, but i dont know its not working?

Comment: place a `debugger;` inside `success`. Press `F12` while running in browser!! Just try debugging line by line using `F10`

Comment: iam getting these error, Type error: invalid 'in' operand a

Comment: then its not in proper format as you have mentioned! do one thing try assigning your response data to some variable and loop the variable inside success!

Comment: iam trying to assigning responce data to some variable, and also its not coming.

Comment: do this - > `var result = $.parseJson(data)` and then replace all `data` inside `each` with `result`

Comment: what version of jQuery you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at loading `JSON` data using an `HTTP GET` request (you can also use POST).

**JSON jQuery Syntax:**

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] );
```

> url – A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> data – A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.
>
> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) – A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

[Download Example](http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/jquery4u/2011/03/json-example-jquery4u.zip)

Code reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).