# Convert JSON into Array of JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript, json

I got a JSON result from PHP that looks like this below.  I need to convert it into an array of objects like shown at the bottom.

How can I achieve this?

What I have

**Milestones JSON**

```
[
  {
    "id":0,
    "name":"None"
  },
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Milestone 1"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Milestone 2"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"Milestone 3"
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "name":"Milestone 4"
  }
]
```

---

What I need

**Milestones Array Of OBjects**

```
var taskMilestonesArray = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'None',
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Milestone 1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Milestone 2',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Milestone 3',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Milestone 4',
}];
```

---

**UPDATE**

I just realized they are both in almost exact same format already.  I just need to pass the array of objects into a library that expects it to be in that format and I don't think I can pass the JSON in.

Comment: `var taskMilestonesArray = JSON.parse( php_json_string )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON string to Javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420567/convert-json-string-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that JSON in a string (for the sake of the example, I will assume you have a variable named `yourJsonString` that holds your json), you can parse it:

```
var taskMilestonesArray = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) api to convert json string to the javascript object.

```
var taskMilestonesArray = JSON.parse('< milestones json string >');
```