# For loop loops through every character from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having some trouble with my array.

It loops through every character of the array, so including the `[` and `"`.

My code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   alert(array[i]);
   //Do something
}
```

The array looks like this: `["1", "2", "1"]`

Comment: what does `alert(typeof array)` say

Comment: It seems your array is a `string`

Comment: It seems your "array" is not an array, but a JSON representation of an array: a string.

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah, yes, I see now. It says `string`

Comment: Probably a json to be more precise.

Comment: So I will have to convert this somehow

Comment: `var array = JSON.parse(arrayString);`

Comment: @KamilLatosinski— "a json"? JSON is a notation, the OP likely has a string that is an array in JSON format, or a javascript array literal.

Comment: One of the chars is a microJSON ;)

Comment: @mplungjan In my opinion you should create a answer to this question. I will accept it as correct, because you are the first that came with the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

Understanding that you had a string representation of an array, you can convert it to array using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
var arrayString='["1", "2", "1"]',
    array = JSON.parse(arrayString);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   console.log(array[i]);
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @mplungjan!

Answer (score 2):

You are looping a string and thus it shows characters of the string. You might want to convert the string into an array before looping. The best way will be to use JSON.parse function.

```
// Add this
array = JSON.parse(array);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
alert(array[i]);
//Do something
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice while writing the answer. That "Go away" was unneeded though.

Comment: So I removed it... I forgot the ;)

Comment: Nice job in the comments. But shouldn't you try to answer instead? Most of the searchers do not tend to search in the comments and look directly in the answers.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry but I think it is much clearer if the comments are summerized or illustrated on an answer otherwise this site would look like an old ages forum.

Comment: Fair enough. I did not feel it was worth answering since the comments already gave OP the reason. Anyway - I converted my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
array=JSON.parse(array);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   alert(array[i]);
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Of course an answer is still needed. The person posting the answer as a comment made the mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser has the JSON object then

```
JSON.parse(string);
```

or if you have jQuery

```
$.parseJSON(string);
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9420607/5326667