# How to convert json string into array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, html

```
code page="c#"
   { "data":    [{"CUSTOMER_NAME_ID":"INV10143","CUSTOMER_NAME":"rossperry","CUSTOMER_NAME_PAN":"AVRPG4803D","EMAIL":"rossperry1@gmail.com","PLAN_NAME":"MOSt special Plan   Growth","DATE":"\/Date(1452452300000)\/","AMOUNT":5000.0000,"CONFIRM_UNITS":314.832}]}
```

THis is what I am getting after parsing string into json object but I am not able to map into array.actually I am getting data after parsing which I mentioned aboove how csan i get object.why giving me error that obj.data undefined

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420567/convert-json-string-to-javascript-array

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean 'there is data'? Why can't you use `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Sorry Everyone,actually I did some mistake thats why I had problem  and now I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.ParseJSON(string)` for converting json string to array.

Comment: It is giving me error that parsejson is not a function of that one

Comment: $.parseJSON is not a function this is what i am getting error when I use this

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ParseJSON(your-string);
```

parseJSON was added in version 1.4.1, so if you're using earlier versions, it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've got a typo in your question but JSON doesn't look valid.

If however it is valid then you'll want something like:

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse("{ \"data\": [object1, object2] }");
var array = parsedJSON.data;
```

**UPDATE**

After formatting your updated JSON everything looks ok. Not sure why you're getting undefined

```js
var json = "{\"data\":[{\"CUSTOMER_NAME_ID\":\"INV10143\",\"CUSTOMER_NAME\":\"rossperry\",\"CUSTOMER_NAME_PAN\":\"AVRPG4803D\",\"EMAIL\":\"rossperry1@gmail.com\",\"PLAN_NAME\":\"MOSt special Plan   Growth\",\"DATE\":\"/Date(1452452300000)/\",\"AMOUNT\":5000,\"CONFIRM_UNITS\":314.832}]}"

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json);
document.write('<pre><code>' + JSON.stringify(parsedJSON.data,null,2) + '</code></pre>');
```

Comment: parsedJSON.data is undefined showing me this debugger and only parsed json having all values and i am not able to map into array

Comment: Could you add your actual JSON separately to your Question?

Comment: Yes I wrote seperately in question ,I updated my question You can check now